# How to reshape a data frame with two columns to wide format?

Tags: r

I want to reshape the following data frame

```
x <- structure(
    list(name = c("HT", "AT", "HG", "AG"),
         conv = c(2L, + 2L, 3L, 4L)),
    .Names = c("name", "conv"), row.names = 1:4, class = "data.frame")

> x
  name conv
1   HT    2
2   AT    2
3   HG    3
4   AG    4
```

into

```
  conv  x.1  x.2
1    2   HT   AT
2    3   HG   NA
3    4   AG   NA
```

In the final data frame there should be a row for every distinct value of
`conv`, and as many `x.?` columns as there are rows in the original data
frame for that particular value of `conv`, filling with NAs when necessary.  I don't care about the column names.

I tried `reshape` but I can't get it to work, because it seems that it needs
a third column that I don't have:

```
> reshape(x, idvar='conv', direction='wide')
Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , timevar) : undefined columns selected
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something you can try:

```
xmax <- max(table(x$conv))
xsplit <- split(x, x$conv)
xsplit <- sapply(xsplit, function(tab){c(tab$name, rep(NA, xmax-length(tab$name)))})
x2 <- data.frame(conv=x$conv[!duplicated(x$conv)], t(xsplit), stringsAsFactors=F)
colnames(x2)[-1]<-paste("x",1:xmax,sep=".")
x2
#  conv x.1  x.2 
#2    2  HT   AT
#3    3  HG <NA>
#4    4  AG <NA>
```

*NB*: with reshape, you can do what's below but I don't think that's what you want. There may be some parameters to set so you get what you want but I'm really not a `reshape` expert :-(

```
reshape(data=x, v.names="name", timevar="name", idvar="conv", direction="wide")
#  conv name.HT name.AT name.HG name.AG
#1    2      HT      AT    <NA>    <NA>
#3    3    <NA>    <NA>      HG    <NA>
#4    4    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>      AG
```

Answer (score 3):

using `data.table v1.9.5`:

```
require(data.table)
dcast(setDT(x), conv ~ paste0("x.", x[, seq_len(.N), by=conv]$V1), value.var="name")
#    conv x.1 x.2
# 1:    2  HT  AT
# 2:    3  HG  NA
# 3:    4  AG  NA
```

You can install it by following the instructions [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation).